# React context returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I want to use context in React to pass authentication information to child components. My context provider is in a file named `AuthContext.js`:

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

class AuthContextProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        isAuthenticated: false
    };
    toggleAuth = () => {
        this.setState({ isAuthenticated: !this.state.isAuthenticated });
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <AuthContext.Provider value={{...this.state, toggleAuth: this.toggleAuth}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default AuthContextProvider;
```

But when I'm accesing the context from the child components, it returns `undefined`

```
import { AuthContext } from "../contexts/AuthContext";

export default function ButtonAppBar() {
    return(
        <AuthContext.Consumer>{(authContext) => {
            console.log(authContext);
        }}</AuthContext.Consumer>
    );
}
```

After checking the React Developer Tools, I came to see that `ButtonAppBar` is not inside `AuthContextProvider`. Imports are correct. Any reason for this apart from import errors?

[image: Screenshot of react developer tools]

**React version:** 16.9.0

Comment: How are you using AuthContextProvider? what version of react are you using?

Comment: @Federkun I'm using React 16.9.0. And I'm using context consumer to access the context...if that's what you're asking?

Comment: I'm asking if you can confirm that AuthContextProvider is used as a parent component of `ButtonAppBar`, maybe provide an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at this [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-goldwasser-0cq18) you will see that your code is correct and should be working if you did everything all right.

## Reasons that can make it not work

- Maybe you are importing it wrong? Please check how you import it.
- Maybe `ButtonAppBar` isn't inside `AuthContextProvider`.

For the context to work, the consumer needs to be inside of the provider.

This will work

```
  <AuthContextProvider>
    <ButtonAppBar /> {// consumer inside the provider }
  </AuthContextProvider>
```

This will not work

```
  <AuthContextProvider>
      ...
  </AuthContextProvider>
  <ButtonAppBar /> {// consumer outside the provider }
```

In the screenshot from the question, you don't have `AuthContextProvider` wrapping the routes, so you will never be able to get the context.

You didn't provided the code correctly but I'm guessing that what you need to do is

```
<App>
    <AuthContextProvider> {// AuthContextProvider wrapping routes so you can get the context}
        <BrowserRouter>
            ...
        </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthContextProvider>
</App>
```

Comment: It's the second reason. I've updated my question, can you please take a look?

Comment: @AnubhavDas Please share where and how you use `AuthContextProvider` and `ButtonAppBar`.

Comment: In your screenshot, you aren't using `AuthContextProvider`, you should put it around the router so all routes can have that context.